# Sink for line-by-line file IO with backpressure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a file processing job that currently uses akka actors with manually managed backpressure to handle the processing pipeline, but I've never been able to successfully manage the backpressure at the input file reading stage.

This job takes an input file and groups lines by an ID number present at the start of each line, and then once it hits a line with a new ID number, it pushes the grouped lines to a processing actor via message, and then continues with the new ID number, all the way until it reaches the end of the file.

This seems like it would be a good use case for Akka Streams, using the File as a sink, but I'm still not sure of three things:

1) How can I read the file line by line?

2) How can I group by the ID present on every line? I currently use very imperative processing for this, and I don't think I'll have the same ability in a stream pipeline.

3) How can I apply backpressure, such that I don't keep reading lines into memory faster than I can process the data downstream?

Comment: Questions: how do you manage backpressure right now? Are you reading file from single node? Are you using akka cluster for processing?

Comment: I don't manage the backpressure. I've tried a few things but they were all hacky (like long-poll `ask`ing for `Continue` messages from the processing actor, and manually iterating the read, which was incredibly brittle). So I chose to hack it instead by giving my app enough heap space to consume the whole input file into memory. I can't do that anymore, as I have to deploy this to a shared server and I can't gobble up everyone's memory anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Akka streams' `groupBy` is one approach.  But groupBy has a `maxSubstreams` param which would require that you to know that max # of ID ranges up front.  So: the solution below uses `scan` to identify same-ID blocks, and `splitWhen` to split into substreams:

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  def extractId(s: String) = {
    val a = s.split(",")
    a(0) -> a(1)
  }

  val file = new File("/tmp/example.csv")

  private val lineByLineSource = FileIO.fromFile(file)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 1024))
    .map(_.utf8String)

  val future: Future[Done] = lineByLineSource
    .map(extractId)
    .scan( (false,"","") )( (l,r) => (l._2 != r._1, r._1, r._2) )
    .drop(1)
    .splitWhen(_._1)
    .fold( ("",Seq[String]()) )( (l,r) => (r._2, l._2 ++ Seq(r._3) ))
    .concatSubstreams
    .runForeach(println)

  private val reply = Await.result(future, 10 seconds)
  println(s"Received $reply")
  Await.ready(system.terminate(), 10 seconds)
}
```

`extractId` splits lines into id -> data tuples. `scan` prepends id -> data tuples with a start-of-ID-range flag.  The `drop` drops the primer element to `scan`.  `splitwhen` starts a new substream for each start-of-range.  `fold` concatenates substreams to lists and removes the start-of-ID-range boolean, so that each substream produces a single element.  In place of the fold you probably want a custom `SubFlow` which processes a streams of rows for a single ID and emits some result for the ID range.  `concatSubstreams` merges the per-ID-range substreams produced by splitWhen back into a single stream that's printed by `runForEach` .

Run with:

```
$ cat /tmp/example.csv
ID1,some input
ID1,some more input
ID1,last of ID1
ID2,one line of ID2
ID3,2nd before eof
ID3,eof
```

Output is:

```
(ID1,List(some input, some more input, last of ID1))
(ID2,List(one line of ID2))
(ID3,List(2nd before eof, eof))
```

Comment: I think I'm following the logic here, but can you explain what `mergeSubstreams` does? I can't seem to find its definition in the API docs.

Comment: I didn't find any docs besides the scaladocs, but I added comments for the stage.  Also, I replaced `mergeSubstreams` with `concatSubstreams` since in this case substreams are started and terminated sequentially (according to ID ranges), and concat will produce output in the same order as ID ranges regardless of any async processing in the subflows.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the easiest way to add "back pressure" to your system without introducing huge modifications is to simply change the mailbox type of the input groups consuming Actor to [BoundedMailbox](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/mailboxes.html#Mailbox_configuration_examples).

1. Change the type of the Actor that consumes your lines to BoundedMailbox with high `mailbox-push-timeout-time`:

   ```
   bounded-mailbox {
     mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMailbox"
     mailbox-capacity = 1
     mailbox-push-timeout-time = 1h
   }

   val actor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[InputGroupsConsumingActor]).withMailbox("bounded-mailbox"))
   ```
2. Create iterator from your file, create grouped (by id) iterator from that iterator. Then just cycle through the data, sending groups to consuming Actor. Note, that send will block in this case, when Actor's mailbox gets full.

   ```
   def iterGroupBy[A, K](iter: Iterator[A])(keyFun: A => K): Iterator[Seq[A]] = {
     def rec(s: Stream[A]): Stream[Seq[A]] =
       if (s.isEmpty) Stream.empty else {
         s.span(keyFun(s.head) == keyFun(_)) match {
         case (prefix, suffix) => prefix.toList #:: rec(suffix)
       }
     }
     rec(iter.toStream).toIterator
   }

   val lines = Source.fromFile("input.file").getLines()

   iterGroupBy(lines){l => l.headOption}.foreach {
     lines:Seq[String] =>
         actor.tell(lines, ActorRef.noSender)
   }
   ```

That's it! 
You probably want to move file reading stuff to separate thread, as it's gonna block. Also by adjusting `mailbox-capacity` you can regulate amount of consumed memory. But if reading batch from the file is always faster than processing, it seems reasonable to keep capacity small, like 1 or 2.

**upd** `iterGroupBy` implemented with `Stream`, tested not to produce `StackOverflow`.